# How to calculate a determinant of a general 2x2 block skew matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, pfaffian

I would like to calculate the determinant of a $2\times2$ block skew matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
         A & B^T \\
         -B & D \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

with $A^T=-A$ and $D^T=-D$, and $A$, $B$ and $D$ are $L\times L$ square complex matrix.

Is there a fast way to calculate the determinant?  By reducing the dimension from $2\times L$ to $L$?

P.S. If there is no fast way to calculate that, how about the a special case when $D=A^\dagger$ ?

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
         A & B^T \\
         -B & A^\dagger \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can express this determinant as 
$$
\det(M) = \det(A - B^TD^{-1}B) \det(D)
$$
but I don't know if this is really any faster.

Comment: Note of course that if the matrices are real and if $L$ is odd, then neither of the matrices will be invertible.

Comment: @ Hao Shi , your total matrix  is a skew symmetric which has no special property. I do not see the point of your question.